# Issue on image width when viewing a my created page in phone

Tags: html, css

I am facing an issue in phone view of my page the page is perfectly displayed in tablet and desktop using chrome dev tools but the grid image is not properly displayed in phone view of the page . each grid item is a flex container whose css property is defined under tile and

[The desktop view of page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPrMN.jpg)

[The tablet/phone view of the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/flt2m.png) 
The links are expected
Problem in phone view [image]

```css
.tile {
  /* TODO: MODULE_CARDS */
  /* 1. Fill in the required properties. */
  display:flex;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  cursor:none;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: stretch;
}


.tile img {
  /* TODO: MODULE_CARDS */
  /* 1. Fill in the required properties. */
  border: none !important;
    border-radius: 25px !important;
    max-width:120%;
    min-width:120%;
    height: 50vh !important;
}

.tile-text {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  
  color:#fff;
  bottom: 32px;

  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size:20px;
}
```

```html
  <div class="container">
    <!-- TODO: MODULE_LAYOUT -->
    <!-- 1. Create the grid like layout as required. -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 mb-4">
        <div class="tile">
          <img src="assets/bengaluru.jpg" class="tile img" alt="bengaluru" >
          <div class = "tile-text" style="text-align:center ">
            <h5>bengaluru</h5>
            <p>100+ places</p>
          </div>
          </div>
        
      </div>
      <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 mb-4">
          <div class="tile">
            <img src="assets/kolkata.jpg" class="tile img" alt="kolkata">
            <div class = "tile-text" style="text-align:center ">
              <h5>kolkata</h5>
              <p>52+ places</p>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 mb-4">
        <div  class="tile">
          <img src="assets/goa.jpg" class="tile img" alt = "goa">
          <div class = "tile-text" style="text-align:center ">
            <h5>goa</h5>
            <p>162+ places</p>
          </div>
          </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 mb-4">
        <div  class="tile">
          <img src="assets/mumbai.jpg" class="tile img" alt = "mumbai">
          <div class = "tile-text" style="text-align:center ">
            <h5>mumbai</h5>
            <p>121+ places</p>
          </div>
          </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 mb-4">
          <div  class="tile">
            <img src="assets/singapore.jpg" class="tile img" alt = "singapore">
            <div class = "tile-text" style="text-align:center ">
              <h5>singapore</h5>
              <p>89+ places</p>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 mb-4">
          <div  class="tile">
            <img src="assets/dubai.jpg" class="tile img"alt = "dubai">
            <div class = "tile-text" style="text-align:center ">
              <h5>dubai</h5>
              <p>74+ places</p>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 mb-4">
        <div  class="tile">
          <img src="assets/malaysia.jpg" class="tile img"alt = "malaysia">
          <div class = "tile-text" style="text-align:center ">
            <h5>malaysia</h5>
            <p>172+ places</p>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class ="col-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 mb-4">
        <div  class="tile">
          <img src="assets/paris.jpg" class="tile img" alt =  "paris">
          <div class = "tile-text" style="text-align:center ">
            <h5>paris</h5>
            <p>150+ places</p>
          </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```